# Code Igniter gives 404 when accessing pages without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm getting 404 errors when accessing via:
http://www1.example.me/z/account/login

Although these work fine:
http://www1.example.me/z/index.php/account/login
http://www1.example.me/z/

.htaccess - got it from [this website](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|www1) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www1.sherzod.me/z/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www1.sherzod.me/z/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Configs:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

**UPDATE**:
Getting this in error_log: 
[Wed Dec 28 17:54:30 2011] [notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!

**Never mind, fixed it.**

Should have been:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ z/index.php/$1 [L]

instead of

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

because the code is inside of z folder. Thanks for visiting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you have 'solved' your problem in your question, your implementation is actually incorrect.

To correctly implement this you should change the RewriteBase directive rather than pointing your rules specifically at a folder.

In your case

```
RewriteBase /z/
```

---

*On a side note, rather than amending your question to say you've fixed it, you should post an answer to the same effect. This prevents the question appearing in unanswered feeds etc.*

Answer (score 1):

first you go to config file....
then set $config['index_page'] = ' ';
then create one file with .htacess extension and write below code in that and save in root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily remove the index.php from url from .htaccess, please check this [url](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for more detail.

Comment: link is not accessible: "Sorry, you do not have permission to access this resource."

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html It's opening at my end . check your firewall, if you have any???